# Return an object other than a task from an async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I return an object other than Task from an async method?
I do some async work in the method, but I need to return something other than Task or return the object inside a Task. I don't know.

Code:

```
public async Task<ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, IServiceProvider>>> GetGroupedSearchStrings(int shopId)
{
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, ISearchString>> result = new Collection<KeyValuePair<int, ISearchString>>();
    IEnumerable<ISearchString> ss = await ShopsExpressions.SearchString(this.Worker.GetRepo<SearchString>().DbSet).Where(s => s.Active && s.ShopId.Equals(shopId)).OrderBy(s => s.DateCreated).ToListAsync();

    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, ISearchString>(1, DEMO));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of `async` is precisely to return a task that represents the current operation, that encapsulates the return value when the method finishes. Why do you **need** to return something else? What's the calling code?

Comment: @Alejandro I do all the database stuff async so I just need to correctly return the result object

Comment: forget about it! figured it out

Answer (score 3):

Async functions *should* be returning a Task.

You need to `await` the Task when you call it.

```
var result = await GetGroupedSearchStrings(shopID);
```

Comment: Technically they just need to return an awaitable pattern - which doesn't have to be `Task[<T>]` - custom awaitables are entirely possible, although to be fair: should only be used with good reason; also, `ValueTask[<T>]` is a perfectly reasonable alternative in many cases. But I agree: most people should be returning either `Task[<T>]` or `ValueTask[<T>]`

Comment: @MarcGravell Wow, I didn't know about `ValueTask[<T>]`.  That is really neat.  Thanks for the info.